# EF6 Code First / Fluent API throwing error with Complex Types

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am experiencing problems in mapping a complex type on a model class (called `Assignment`) using EntityFramework 6.

I have the following `Assignment` model class (only the relevant members are shown):

```
public class Assignment
{ 
    private AssignmentDueByInfo _dueIn;

    public Assignment() {
         _dueIn = new AssignmentDueByInfo(this)
    }

    public virtual AssignmentSettingInfo DueIn
    {
        get { return _dueIn; }
        protected set { _dueIn = value; }
    }
}
```

where `AssignmentSettingInfo` is defined as:

```
public class AssignmentSettingInfo
{
      protected AssignmentSettingInfo(Assignment assignment)
      {
           Assignment = assignment;
      }

      protected readonly Assignment Assignment;

      public virtual int? LessonId { get; protected set; }
      public virtual Lesson Lesson { get; protected set; }
}
```

In Entity Framework 6, I have the following CodeFirst / Fluent API mapping for the `Assignment` class to a table in a database:

```
Property(t => t.DueIn.LessonId).HasColumnName("DueByLessonId");

HasOptional(x => x.DueIn.Lesson)
            .WithMany(x => x.AssignmentsDue)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.DueIn.LessonId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

The mapping is throwing the following error:

> The expression 'x => x.DueIn.Lesson' is not a valid property expression. The expression should represent a property: C#: 't => t.MyProperty'

Why is this happening and how should it be fixed?

Comment: I think this is EF limitation - complex types cannot contain navigation properties.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation (it's quite old, but still holds true):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738472(v=vs.100).aspx

This states that complex types cannot contain navigation properties.

I guess this has to do with the fact they do not have primary keys and they are not managed separately by the context. If they have no PK and cannot be identified by the context, they cannot be 'relationship ends' either.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to make SQL object oriented. The classes you define that represent a database table should be POCOs: fairly simple classes with only get and set properties.

You are doing way too much with fields. If you have to fill a field in one of the table classes, think again. I've never seen an example where the class that represents a database table needed any field, other than a simple get/set property.

If one of the classes relates to another class, this is done by foreign key, not by `this`.

Class `Assignment` represents a database table. This table is supposed to have certain columns and relations to other tables using foreign keys. Class `Assignment` should not contain smart things that are not part of the table.

for example I see that `Assignment` has a field named `_dueIn` of type `AssignmentDueByInfo`. Outsiders can access this field, but for them this field is not an `AssignmentDueByInfo`, but an `AssignmentSettingInfo`.

Decide for yourself what columns the `Assignment` should have.

Is there a reason to put the columns for an `AssignmentSettingInfo` in a different table? If I look at your code there can't be an `AssignmentSettingInfo` without an 'Assignment`and there can't be an`Assignment`without an`AssignmentSettingInfo`. So why put them in separate tables?

Another problem is the relation between `AssignmentSettingInfo` and `Lesson`. Is this a zero-or-one to one? [Follow these guide lines](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

If you'd put 'Assignment`and`AssignmentSettingInfo` in one table your code would be like

```
class Assignment
{
     public int Id {get; set;}

     // every assignment has exactly one AssignmentSettingInfo
     // use aggregation (in entity framework terms: complextype)
     public AssignmentSettingInfo AssignmentSettingInfo {get; set;}
}

[ComplexType]
class AssignmentSettingInfo
{
    // Every AssignmentSettingInfo has zero or one Lesson
    public virtual Lesson Lesson { get; set; }
}
```

class Lesson
   {
        public int Id {get; set;}

```
    // relation between Line and AssignmentSettingInfo
    ...
}
```

I couldn't figure out the relation between `Line` and `AssignmentSettingInfo`. Visit:

- [One-to-One](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)
- [one-to-many?](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

If you really want the `AssignmentSettingInfo` in a different table, configure it as a one-to-one method as shown in the links

Comment: The reason for splitting out the AssignmentSettingInfo is that the functionality of that class is more than shown, and it is reused elsewhere. I was favouring composition over inheritance.  A lot has been stripped out of the classes shown above; the fields are there for a reason but one that is outside the scope of the question.